# Updating model on save vs count objects in the ListView - what's better performance-wise?

Tags: python, django, performance

I'm creating a forum script. Currently I'm trying to optimize things and looking for answer from more experienced developers.

For example - let's assume we are working on ListView of Category, which should list all threads within the same forum category. For every thread in category we are listing fields such as:

- Thread name
- Thread author
- **Number of posts**
- Number of views
- Last post details (author, date)

What is the best performance approach to calculate number of posts? Currently I'm thinking about 3 solutions.

1. Use `annotate()` on queryset
2. add IntegerField `posts_number` to `Thread` model. Increment the value on `save()` in `Post` model and decrement on `delete()`
3. Use memcache to cache read-only SQL queries and force cache refresh on every `save()` in `Post` model.

I'm aware this is not an issue with low traffic forums, but I would love to know what's the best approach

Comment: Note that there are other considerations than performance here. In particular, denormalisation (which is your option 2) is hard to get right and easy for the counts to get out of sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally handle the posts count on the thread model itself not as an extra `model.field` but as a method or a property and cache the evaluated value one time and invalidate cache for that **thread only** when there is a new post on that thread. This way

- not all the cached counts are invalidated when there is new post on another thread
- I can access the post count from all over the application without a database hit
- you don't need to query each time for posts count only when is a change to posts count (deletion and insertion)

And for your solution

1. Annotation is faster than calculating count per thread in a for loop but then you have to count it every time even when there has been no new Post..
2. Integer field on the Thread model is prone to data inconsistency especially in the long run (for example from the admin if 2 users are accessing it or a new post is created while you are working in the admin. So you might end up writing thread safe code with locks or end up writing extra boiler plate for making it read-only e.g. taking care of user writing on it with an '**all**' serializer and etc.)
3. For your `memcache` solution i think it's best when they have not been bind together (new post on thread `A` won't make you recalculate count for all the threads)

plus it's not a good practice to handle updating cache in model.save since it's called all the time (e.g. editing a post) it's better to **invalidate and not update** cache where you actually create or delete a post (e.g. in the admin and writing a custom form, or in the your view or `serializer.perform_create` or in signals but watch out for soft deletes and etc..)

Update:

Since your question is about performance you should take a look [django ORM optimization doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/optimization/) most importantly `select_related and prefetch_related`

Also if you don't need the python object after getting them from the database and just need their value [don't convert them to python objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/optimization/)

Comment: Let's see if I got this right. So you create a property/method that returns number of Thread's post, so it gets cached per single Thread (not Queryset as I proposed) then you invalidate cache on Post's save() if it's added parent's Thread, right?

Comment: @PeterR. Pretty much.. though i prefer to avoid cache invalidation in post.save cause when you edit a post that method is called. and i think it won't be called when you delete a post.. so i'd suggest you do it some place else.. but yeah that's pretty much the idea